# Storing files on TFS

Tags: tfs, repository

I am working with my co-worker on some files, that are in TFS repository. We have to share these files frequently, however, in the process of our development they are neither compilable, nor working properly. We don't want to put them in the repository, because the rest of the crew shall have problems with compiling the solution. However, the manual sharing would be rather painful. Is there a way to put files on TFS, but not inside repository? (mark as temporary, not finished or something like that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a shelveset - if you shelve your set of changes then your colleague can pick them up and the other members of the team will never see them.  It is a bit of a PITA as you need to have 2 shelvesets (1 each as you can only update your own).  The only other way is to branch and then merge when you have compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to branch the code into a new branch that the two of you use.  When you are done working on the file, and it will no longer break the main build, you can then merge that file back down to the development branch.